# React navigate issue on passing params

Tags: reactjs, navigation, parameter-passing

I am new to react. I am trying to pass the parameters to another component using navigate.page is redirected successfully but I am facing error while reading param values.

App.js:

```
 <Router>
    <Routes>
    <Route path="/test" element ={<testLayout/>}
    <Route path="/valid" element ={<validation/>}
</Routes>
</Router>
```

root page:

```
class testLayout extends Component {
render(){
<div>
<Selection/>

</div>
}
}
export default testLayout;
```

Firstpage:

```
export default function Selection(){

const navigate= useNavigate();
    const handleclick = (params) => {
    let id= params.id;
    let path = '/valid';
    navigate(path,{docId:id});
    }

return(
    <DataGrid onCellClick={handleclick} />
);

    
}
```

Valid page:

```
Import React, {Component} from "react";
class validation extends Component
{
render(){

const {navigation } = this.props;

let rs= navigation.getParam('docId','default value')

return(
<div>
<h1> hi {rs}<h1>
</div>
);
}
}
export default validation;
```

I am getting bellow error
**Can't read properties of undefined (reading 'getParam')**

I know somewhere I am missing something.
Can anyone help me to fix this.

Thanks

Comment: can you share more the code of the component? using react router?

Comment: @Quak_2023 i just update the code

Comment: so FirstPage is not a route? you cannot call useNavigate() outside a router component. and your not passing any prop named navigation

Comment: @Quak_2023 yes i can edit the first page code.

Comment: @Quak_2023 i add the root page code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to get props passed with navigate (useNavigate) u need the useLocation hook which cannot be used inside a class component so you can use a wrapper like you did with the selection component and use it within to extract the props
it would look like this

```
class Validation extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <div>im Rendered </div>
        <Wrapper />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Validation;

function Wrapper() {
  const {
    state: { docId }
  } = useLocation();
  return <div>im Rendered {docId}</div>;
}
```

also when passing i changed this line  `navigate(path, { state: { docId: id } });`

here a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-class-based-component-react-forked-kgt9w3?file=%2Fsrc%2FSelection.js)